# Express biorthogonal vectors in terms of one another

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

The non-coplanar vector triples a,b,c and a′,b′,c′ are reciprocal or biorthogonal if a·a′= b·b′= c·c′= 1 and b·a′= c·a′= a·b′ = c·b′ = a·c′ = b·c′ = 0.

I need help to express a′,b′,c′ in terms of a,b,c.

Answer (score 1):

The primes vectors have no components on the original vectors except its letter's vector.
Assuming we are in three dimensions, we are only left with vectors that are proportional to each other.
Finally the norm of the prime vector is the inverse of the nirm of the original ones by the first relations.

Comment: how would I express the prime vectors in terms of the original vectors then?